# Error express-simple , primordials is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, backend, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to use yeoman and express-simple generator for the first time using this command :

> yo express-simple

but I got this message :

> Error express-simple

> primordials is not defined

I've tried to reinstall the generator